# IPython Notebook freezes on startup

Tags: python, browser, ipython

When I launch ipython from the command line, there is no problem whatsoever. But when I invoke ipython notebook, I first get the 'dashboard' tab. If I click 'New Notebook', I get a new tab that remains completely blank (no "In[]" marker, just completely frozen, blank, white browser window).

I tried modifying the profile configuration file that I usually use and getting rid of everything in it (so that it should be just like invoking ipython natively, none of my extra libraries are trying to be imported, etc.). This didn't help at all.

I have also tried running IPython notebook with MathJax turned off, changing the port with `--port=` to run on ports that I know are unused and fine, and going into the Firefox settings and turning off the use of a proxy (to be sure to avoid the known Firefox issue with proxies).

None of that stuff helped at all. It matters to get this working in Firefox as well, since the code will be ported to a community Linux server at work where a number of people use IPython Notebook and only Firefox is available. So for the moment, just switching to a different browser is not viable.

Couldn't find any helpful bug reports or previous web pages describing this sort of problem. Any help would be appreciated.

System: running Red Hat 5.5, IPython version 0.12, and Firefox 3.6

**Added**: I opened the Firefox error console while trying all this, and now I am seeing an error that says the following.

```
console is not defined
http://127.0.0.1:8892/static/js/notebook.js
```

I'm searching now for how to resolve this, but pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: have you tried running this on another system? (e.g. your linux server or a different install of linux)--might help you isolate what the problem is.  Also, can you give the output of running `iptest`? (the ipython test runner)

Comment: The error appears to be a JavaScript console problem; it's basically the same as mentioned [here](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/IPython-User-Notebook-console-is-not-defined-td4355342.html), but with Firefox instead of the browser mentioned there. It's a shame the iPython folks who replied to that thread just assumed it was the old browser and did not try to diagnose that issue... now it's happening with the supposedly stable Firefox.

Comment: Again, it would be helpful to see if switching browsers/computers helps or `iptest` comes up with any issues.  That helps to decrease the # of possibilities for the source of this error.  After that, you can figure out how to make it work on your computer with Firefox.

Comment: It appears to be a version issue; by installing Firebug, it made the console error disappear, but now the notebook page is not interactive. In searching around, it looks like it is the Firefox version (3.6). It does not support WebSockets, and apparently iPython requires this. Since it's a Linux server at work, I don't have the ability to upgrade Firefox. I disagree that any of the 10 `iptest` tests are relevant for this.

Comment: okay, if it specifically has to do with Firefox 3.6, then you're right that `iptest` probably won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [IPython docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#browser-compatibility), the Notebook supports the following browsers:

> - Chrome
> - Safari
> - Firefox 6 and above
> - Firefox 4 and 5: These browsers have WebSocket support, but it is disabled by default. If you are unable to  upgrade, you can enable it by entering about:config in the URL bar and then setting network.websocket.enabled and network.websocket.override-security-block to true.

The notebook is not compatible with FF3.  It should give a better message about the browser's deficiency than it seems to be doing.  You are right that iptest results are totally unrelated to this.

Comment: Upgrading Firefox fixed the issue. Hopefully this post will be an effective way to help people when absence of WebSockets (due to old browsers or otherwise) causes problems. I agree that this should be better handled in iPython... I had to manually debug Javascript code before ever getting any warnings about WebSockets.

Comment: If you're interested, I have a followup question: how does IPython choose the first default notebook directory? I know I can change this within the ipython_notebook_config.py, but I am curious how IPython goes about choosing the directory the first time that the default config files are created. It's picking up an unusual directory as the default on my work station.

Comment: The default notebook dir is the cwd where it is called.

Comment: It's picking up a different directory for me... one that's even on a totally different Linux server and certainly isn't the cwd from which I launch iPython. It's probably some kind of network setting on our side, but I was hoping knowing more about iPython's convention could help me find it. I guess editing the config file is the best option. Thanks for all your help, btw... it bodes very well for IPython. I was skeptical that the notebook was just a poorly maintained convenience thing, but you guys are taking good care of it.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/notebookmanager.py#L37) is the code that sets the default value - it is the cwd. You can override this with ipython_notebook_config.py or passing `--notebook-dir=foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to launch a big Notebook, this Notebook may contain a lot of output data that you should strip manually or using the nbstripout utility which precisely strips output from Jupyter and iPython Notebooks.

```
pip3 install --upgrade nbstripout

nbstripout MY_BIG_NOTEBOOK_FILE.ipynb
```